# Get Excel data via rest API from a spreadsheet in a SharePoint (gov) site

Tags: sharepoint-rest-api

I'm trying to get data from a SharePoint site using the rest API but I'm not sure I'm doing it in the right way. This is what I have been trying in Postman.

I have successfully generated the access token and I sending a GET to:

```
https://{{ServerName}}/sites/{{SiteName}}/_vti_bin/ExcelRest.aspx/Shared%20Documents/Book.xlsx/model
```

Request header:

```
Content-Type:application/json;odata=verbose
Accept:application/json;odata=verbose
Authorization:Bearer {{bearerToken}}
```

I have been following the instructions in this link https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-docs/blob/main/docs/general-development/resources-uri-for-excel-services-rest-api.md

I get 401 Unauthorized

```
{
    "Message": "There was an error processing the request.",
    "StackTrace": "",
    "ExceptionType": ""
}
```

From this response it does look like an authorization issue, but I want to confirm I'm sending the right GET request.

I also tried different ways to build the address, like:

```
https://{{ServerName}}/_vti_bin/ExcelRest.aspx/sites/{{SiteName}}/Shared%20Documents/Book.xlsx/model

https://{{ServerName}}/sites/{{SiteName}}/_vti_bin/ExcelRest.aspx/sites/{{SiteName}}/Shared%20Documents/Book.xlsx/model
```

But they all give the same response.

If it is in fact an authorization issue, this is the permission request XML I used when I created the app to access data:

```
<AppPermissionRequests AllowAppOnlyPolicy="true">
  <AppPermissionRequest Scope="http://sharepoint/content/sitecollection/web" Right="FullControl"/>
</AppPermissionRequests>
```

Maybe the Excel rest API requires a different permission?